# Create database in custom folder

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create database in custom folder? Like:
`mysql> create database test FOLDER='/home/username/db_folder/'`?

Comment: 1. create a folder on the target drive for the data base you want to create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. create a folder on the target drive for the data base you want to create.
2. make an mlink with the name of the database you want so if db name is db1 :

> ```
> mklink /d db1 g:\db1data
> ```

1. on win7 need to start cmd prompt as admin - right click run as administrator.
2. g:\db1data  should exist before running the mlink command and stop mysql before you do this, restart to see the new data base.
3. just used this to make a db on a RAM drive. Plan to copy it to a disk backed 'normal' db before shutdown!

Reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/symbolic-links.html

Used tool imdisk with command :

> imdisk -a -t vm -m g: -s 2g

To create the RAM disk first.

Comment: Was it introduced in 5.6?

Comment: I dont think so http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-symbolic-links.html

Comment: Did you use imdisk ? I made a new drive with 2GB RAM but the maybe too big? My db time did not reduce much. went down from 1 hour 50 minutes to 1 hour and 45 mins.

Answer (score 4):

No its not possible .. there is no `FOLDER` switch for the `create database` command : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

MySQL uses the folder specified in the `my.cnf` file for the placement of its files - look for the `datadir` option in the `.cnf` file.

[Link to the docs for datadir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir)

Comment: Can use mlink on windows, need admin accesss

Answer (score 4):

In Linux environment it can be painless using simple symbolic links:

1. First check in `my.cnf` [`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`] for database files destination.
2. Let's say that destination is in folder `/var/lib/mysql/` and yours database name is "abccompany"
3. Stop mysql database
4. Move folder [`var/lib/mysql/abccompany`] to new destination (let say "/diskY")
5. Make symbolic link:

   ```
   ln  -s  /diskY/abccompany   abccompany
   ```
6. Start mysql database and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB tables could be placed in other directory if file-per-table used
[MySQL 5.6 Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html)

Answer (score 1):

in MSSQL, You can create using the following query.

```
CREATE DATABASE foo ON  PRIMARY 
(NAME = 'foo', FILENAME = 'E:\TestDBs\foo.mdf')
 LOG ON 
( NAME = 'foo_log', FILENAME = 'E:\TestDBs\foo_log.ldf')
```

the above query will create a database named foo(db file and log file) in E:\TestDBs directory.

P.S. this query can be generated using "New Database" dialog box in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Wrong database type (MSSQL vs. MySQL).